# SharePoint 2010 - Edit WebPartPage not possible

Tags: web-part, versioning, web-part-pages, editing-menu

I want to edit a SharePoint 2010 WebPartPage over the GUI.
But when I press the edit button, nothing happens.
Only the webbrowser (IE8) displays a javascript error on the page.

Knows anybody this error? Is there a solution for this problem?

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; >SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC >6.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC EA 2)
> Timestamp: Tue, 2 Aug 2011 15:45:16 UTC
>
> Message: 'Pub' is undefined
> Line: 2
> Char: 186407
> Code: 0
> URI: http://mysharepoint.de/_layouts/sp.ribbon.js?rev=F%2BUEJ66rbXzSvpf7nN69wQ%3D%3D

Comment: Having the same problem after migration to SP2010. People with contribute permission cannot edit Web Parts but Collection Admins can. Contributors cannot even edit Web Parts that they created prior to the SP2010 migration. Any advice on a solution?? We get the same error shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possible causes

1) If you can edit other web part pages without an issue then it is most likely one of the web parts on the page that has JS that is breaking the SP JS.

2) if there is a custom Web Part on the page that does any validation using the .Net validation controls, then it needs to handle the post-back that SP does in order to begin Edit Mode without triggering the validation.  If it is attempting to validate on this post-back, then it would prevent edit mode.

3) If you cannot edit any pages and have a customized master page then the issue might be on the master page itself.  This is especially likely if you are using a 2007 master page in sp 2010.

4) if none of the above are true then look for things that might break the DOM.  Things like multiple HEAD or BODY sections or seriously malformed HTML.